# Webpack Uglify Plugin Causing String.split to malfunction in chrome 51 only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, uglifyjs

[image: screenshot of issue]

I'm seeing a super weird issue where the minification process for my app is causing unexpected side effects.

my only webpack plugins are these two.

```
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: '"production"'
    },
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
```

in the latest version of chrome, if i run this snippet of js `'fooBar'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)` the result is `["foo", "Bar"]`, which is expected. it also works fine in chrome 51 on other pages.

however, on my page, in chrome 51, the result is `["fooBar"]`.

if i remove the uglifyjs plugin, it starts working again.

I thought maybe it was specific to the tools i was using and not necessarily my build, but i pulled down create-react-app and it's also using uglifyjs, but it worked fine in chrome 51.

I also tried minifying with uglify js directly instead of using the plugin and that worked. i've been looking through the code of the uglify plugin to see if something stands out as wrong but nothing does.

I also checked in the console to see if the method had been replaced, but when i said `str.split` it still returned `function split() { [native code] }`

I've been searching through the libraries i'm using and my code to see if anything looks like it could changing the behavior of a native method like this, but i don't really see anything. i've tried removing babel-polyfill and a few other things to see if they were causing the issue, but nothing seemed to make a difference. Considering the split method is still native, i'm still shocked that anything that happens in the browser could make a difference at all to its behavior.

Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this? Thanks.

Comment: just to entertain me, try without mangle: `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({mangle : false}),`

Comment: it did the same thing :(

Comment: Hmm, I think the "method might have been replaced" was a good idea. I would also try to rename the function to something else. Also update to latest webpack/uglifyJsPlugin. (I've ran into similar issues, and I think there has been quite recent changes). And then there is of course the "compress: false" option, but nobody wants to use that. :/

Comment: wouldn't mangle regex just mangle more than the default options but less than mangle false?

Comment: Aha, found something: `keep_fnames -- default false. Pass true to not mangle function names. Useful for code relying on Function.prototype.name. `

Comment: oh i meant the default options to the plugin. but that's a good point. ill try to run uglifyjs directly with the options webpack uses to see if it makes a difference

Comment: Sorry, I kept editing comments instead of making new ones (so I'm not sure you saw it). Did you try with `{keep_fnames: true}`?

Comment: i tried keep_fnames. it still didn't work. i really don't see how any javascript could change the behavior of a native function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug uglify caused by the reduce_vars option.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2199#issuecomment-302226607